# Changing multiple images with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

I'm trying to set up a page with multiple images (cards from a game)
By default, cards start off showing the back.
When you click on an image it flips to show you the front.

Here is one of the images and how I change that image:

```
<img src="TechBack.png" id="Tech" onclick=diffImageTech(this) />

<script>    
function diffImageTech(img) 
{
   if(img.src.match(/TechBack/)) img.src = "TechFront.png";
   else img.src = "TechBack.png";
}       
</script>
```

What I also want to happen is if Card A is already flipped to front image, then when you click on Card B, Card A will flip to back and Card B will flip to front image.

Here is what I am trying to make work from some googling:

```
<img src="CelebBack.png" id="CelebBack" onclick=diffImageCelebs(this) />
<img src="TechBack.png" id="TechBack" onclick=diffImageTech(this) />


<script>    
function diffImageCelebs(element) 
{
var a = element.getElementById("CelebBack").item(0);
var b = element.getElementById("TechBack").item(0);

var aa = a.getAttribute("src");
var bb = b.getAttribute("src");

if bb = "TechFront.png" 

{   bb = "TechBack.png";    }

else    {   "TechBack.png"; }

b.setAttribute("src", bb);

if aa = "CelebBack.png";
{ aa = "CelebFront.png"; }
   else {  "CelebBack.png";  }

a.setAttribute("src", aa);

   }        
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you should store state of image, back image src, and front image src. then you can manipulate it with one function.

```js
function diffImageTech(img) 
{
   if(img.getAttribute('data-display')=='front'){
      img.setAttribute('data-display', 'back');
      img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('data-back'));
   }
   else {
    img.setAttribute('data-display','front');
      img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('data-front'));
   }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/cfd0d6&text=CelebBack" data-back="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/cfd0d6&text=CelebBack" data-front="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/cfd0d6&text=CelebFront" id="CelebBack"  onclick=diffImageTech(this) />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/cfd0d6&text=TechBack"   data-back="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/cfd0d6&text=TechBack"  data-front="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/cfd0d6&text=TechFront" id="TechBack" onclick=diffImageTech(this) />
```